# connecting to mysql from localhost when data is on server (cpanel)

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I am trying to connect to mysql hosted on server. Panel used is cpanel. But i am not able to connect to the database. Running php code on local system using xamp.
Error is below.

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 5
```

Even i have put the % as the wildcard entry to allow all host but no luck. Any ideas what wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try using port number with the domain in `mysql_connect();` . The default mysql port number is `3306`.

```
mysql_connect('yourdomain.com:3306', 'user', 'password');
```